# skewX() CSS3 Property

Tags: css

I have a practical use for the CSS3 skewX property.  I have written a simple image accordian-like script with jQuery.  Images are skewed (already, not in CSS) as part of the design and in order to make the correct areas clickable, the containing divs need to be skewed.

The problem is that in skewing the div, the image is skewed aswell.  Skewing a skewed image does not look good.

One solution I've tried is resetting the skewX value to 0deg on the image, but to no avail.  In the fiddle, I haven't included the accordian as this isn't necessary to the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/yM49N/2/

```
<div><img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></div>
```

```css
div {
    -webkit-transform:skewX(200deg);
       -moz-transform:skewX(200deg);
         -o-transform:skewX(200deg);
        -ms-transform:skewX(200deg);
            transform:skewX(200deg);
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: `skewX()` is a function. The property is `transform`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply an inverted `skewX` on `img`:

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-200deg);
       -moz-transform: skewX(-200deg);
         -o-transform: skewX(-200deg);
        -ms-transform: skewX(-200deg);
            transform: skewX(-200deg);
}
```

To make the `div` contain the image properly, you also need to add `overflow: hidden`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yM49N/3/

Comment: Thanks very much, this has solved the double skewing problem.  Sadly, despite the .click() jQuery event changing image ordering in my accordian, when reversing the skew it also reverts the clickable area, defeating the point.

Comment: @sarspazam: Do you have unskewed versions of the images? It might be better to do all the skewing via CSS transforms.

Comment: I could do, but I don't think that'd be the best solution. Rendering of skewed images is terrible in some browsers.

Comment: @sarspazam: Could you not have the `.click()` on the (skewed) `div`, and then find the "active image" (or whatever)? I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but this is the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yM49N/4/